# How to run 'implicity_wait()' in a 'for loop' with respect to Web Scraping using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, data-science

***Actually, I want to scrape the `'title'` and `'product description'` for all the products and from all the `pages`, and then save it into the `'.csv'` file.***

**URL**:- [hhttps://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=1&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop](https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=1&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop)

**This is what, I have tried.**

```
from msilib.schema import Error
from os import sep
from tkinter import ON
from turtle import goto
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

title_list = []
para_list = []
expiry_list = []
country_list = []
importer_list = []
address_list = []

myDict = {'body-art': 3024}


browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\paart\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe')

browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

for item_name in myDict:
    page_num = 1
    while True:
        try:
            page = f"https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/{item_name}/c/{myDict[item_name]}?page_no={page_num}&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id={myDict[item_name]}&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop"

            print(page)

            requests.get(page)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page).content, 'html.parser')
            urls = [item.get("href")
                    for item in soup.find_all("a", class_="css-qlopj4")]
            # print(urls)
            if len(urls) == 0:
                break
            for i in range(0, 2): #Since, it's a huge amount of data, that's why I have taken 2 products on one page, otherwise it will be in the range(0,30). It will cover all the products from an individual pages.
                try:
                    url = urls[i]

                    browser.get("https://www.nykaa.com" + url)

                    title_data = browser.find_elements(
                        By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-1gc4x7i').text

                    print(title_data)

                    for t in title_data:
                        title_list.append(t)

                    browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
                    browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")

                    # Creates "load more" button object.
                    browser.implicitly_wait(20)
                    loadMore = browser.find_element(
                        By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")
                    loadMore.click()
                    browser.implicitly_wait(20)

                    desc_data = browser.find_elements(By.ID, 'content-details')

                    for desc in desc_data:
                        para_details = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                            '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[1]').text
                        para_list.append(para_details)
                        expiry = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                      '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[2]').text
                        expiry_list.append(expiry)
                        country = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                       '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[3]').text
                        country_list.append(country)
                        importer = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                        '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[4]').text
                        importer_list.append(importer)
                        address = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                       '//*[@id="content-details"]/p[5]').text
                        address_list.append(address)

                except:
                    break
        except:
            break
        page_num += 1

title_list = [i.split('.css', 1)[0] for i in title_list]
print(*title_list, sep="\n")
print(*para_list, sep="\n")
print(*expiry_list, sep="\n")
print(*country_list, sep="\n")
print(*importer_list, sep="\n")
print(*address_list, "\n")
data_new = {"Title": title_list, "Para": para_list, "Expiry": expiry_list,
            "Country": country_list, "Importer": importer_list, "Address": address_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_new)
df.to_csv("nykaa_makeup_bodyArt_new.csv")
# print(df)
```

The ***Output***, I am receiving is as:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:30887/devtools/browser/a222842a-7ce3-4070-a684-7e8bb8772279
https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=1&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop
https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=2&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop
https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=3&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop
https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=4&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop
https://www.nykaa.com/makeup/body-art/c/3024?page_no=5&sort=popularity&ptype=lst&id=3024&root=nav_2&dir=desc&order=popularity&eq=desktop



PS E:\Web Scraping - Nykaa>
```

I think, **due to the implicity_wait()** function, it's **not able to fetch the product's title & description**. After **my code run**s, the **'.csv' file is created**, but it's a **blank file**. Maybe, I am wrong. **Please help me regarding this**. Do I need change to add/change some parts of the code?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set `browser.implicitly_wait` multiple times.
`browser.implicitly_wait` is setting the timeout, how much time the `driver` will try to pool the DOM in order to locate an element on the page before it races exception.
`browser.implicitly_wait` is normally set per `driver` session.
This is definetely not a `pause` command like `time.sleep`.
So, in case you need to put a pause in your code you should use `time.sleep` while this is not recommended.
Also, it's much preferably to use Expected Conditions explicit waits rather than `browser.implicitly_wait` since `browser.implicitly_wait` waits for element presence i.e. it will release the run when element is just appeared while it may not be completely rendered.
In order to wait for element completely rendered and containing it text you should use something like

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]")))
```

Where `"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]"` is XPath of element you wishe to get the text from.